# Assigning Elements/Keys to a Dictionary

Tags: python

Im currently assigning a number of elements to a dictionary via list based elements.

Such as :

```
z = mylist
query_dict = {"HOSTNAME":z[0],"TTL":z[1],"CLASS":z[2],"TYPE":z[3],"DETAILS":z[4]}
```

However I wondered if there is a slightly more elegant approach to this, such as the way you can assign variables from a list :

```
a,b,c,d,e = z
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> terms = ["HOSTNAME","TTL","CLASS","TYPE","DETAILS"]
>>> z = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> dict(zip(terms,z))
{'HOSTNAME': 1, 'TYPE': 4, 'CLASS': 3, 'DETAILS': 5, 'TTL': 2}
```

How this works:

the `dict` class has an initialization method which takes an iterable:

```
 |  dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
 |      d = {}
 |      for k, v in iterable:
 |          d[k] = v
```

Where `iterable` contains/yields key value pairs in the form `(key,value)`. Using `zip` we can generate these pairs:

```
>>> zip(terms,z)
[('HOSTNAME', 1), ('TTL', 2), ('CLASS', 3), ('TYPE', 4), ('DETAILS', 5)]
```

Hence we feed in this iterable to the constructor resulting in our desired dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` here:

```
>>> keys = ['HOSTNAME','TTL', 'CLASS', 'TYPE', 'DETAILS']
>>> z = range(5)
>>> dict(zip(keys,z))
{'CLASS': 2, 'TYPE': 3, 'DETAILS': 4, 'TTL': 1, 'HOSTNAME': 0}
```

here `zip` returns a list of tuples containing pairs of elements on the same index:

```
>>> zip(keys,z)
[('HOSTNAME', 0), ('TTL', 1), ('CLASS', 2), ('TYPE', 3), ('DETAILS', 4)]
```

and `dict()` can convert this list into a `dict`:

```
>>> print dict.__doc__
dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
    d = {}
    for k, v in iterable:
        d[k] = v
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your question, you can do for example:

```
fields = ["HOSTNAME", "TTL", "CLASS", "TYPE", "DETAILS"]
query_dict = dict(zip(fields, z))
```